# 2 way clinet server using UDP in C

Tags: c, udp, client

client server has been implemented using UDP in C. The client sends a file name & the server looks up for the file in it's directory. Once it finds it, the server is supposed to send the number of bytes of the file.
The server is sending the data but the client does not receive anything.

Here are the codes:

Server.c : http://pastebin.com/hb8kmaLy

Client.c : http://pastebin.com/ZPdt081u

Comment: No. Most people won't follow links to unknown sites. Post the code *here.* Otherwise the question has no permanent value here and may be deleted. Don't make it harder for people to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you EJP. This was my first post here. I will keep this in mind here after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your server code, I would improve two things.

First,

```
sendto(sockfd, count, count, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen);
```

This does not seem right. The third argument should be the length of the buffer being sent. So, if count is equal to 20000, then sendto would send 20000 bytes starting from the count address. But count is simply an int, so the only storage it has is 4 bytes (or 8 bytes). So you should at least copy the count to a string buffer and then make the 3rd argument the length of the buffer. Note that if count is 110 bytes, then the count buffer should point to "110" string and then third argument shoudl be strlen(count) or 3 in this case.

Second, the count variable needs to be cumulative. In fact, as per "while((count=read(fd,buf,BUFSIZE))>0)", the count variable would be reliably zero or less than zero!

I would try this.

```
char str[16];
int count=0, t;

while((t=read(fd,buf,BUFSIZE))>0) {
    count += t;
    printf("%d",count);
}
sprintf(str, "%d", count);

sendto(sockfd, (void*)str, strlen(str), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, addrlen);
```

Client code is more or less okay. However, we should print an error only if hte returned value is less than zero (or equal to -1). Also you might want to pass sizeof(buf) isntead of strlen(buf) since strlen would stop if it finds a NUL char in the buffer.

```
int ret_bytes;
bzero(buf, sizeof(buf));
ret_bytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen);

printf("Buffer is %s \n", buf);
if (ret_bytes == -1)
    printf("recvfrom() failed");
else
    printf("Received %s (length: %d)\n", buf, ret_bytes);
```

Comment: Or `sendto(sockfd, (char*)&count, sizeof count, ...)` if the receiver is expecting binary ... of course there should also be an `htonl()` in there somewhere in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the head start @manoj-pandey. It works good for the server. The client is still not able to receive the data sent by the server.

Comment: @ManojPandey Thank you for the suggestion on the server part. I have made the changes. Can you please help me evaluate, why the client is unable to receive the message sent by the server?

Comment: I have added a few updates in the client code as well.. I quickly compiled it and it works on my system now..

Comment: @ManojPandey Thank you so much for your valuable inputs. I will make the necessary changes.